# Is there an advantage in using linear algebra as opposed to element by element operations?

Tags: matlab, octave

For example, in a regression problem you might want to sum the square of the difference between two vectors containing data.  I can do this a couple of ways, if we have:

```
    x = [3 4 5 6];
    y = [2 4 6 3];
```

I can write:

```
    sum((x-y).^2)
```

or:

```
    (x-y)*(x-y)'
```

Both of these return the same value, 11.  This is just one example of a calculation that can be done either way, but I wonder if there is a reason to choose one way or the other, and also if there are different types of tasks in which it would be suitable to choose one way over the other.

Answer (score 1):

The first variation could be extended to process multiple sets of input data at once:

```
x = [3 4 5 6;1 2 3 4];
y = [2 4 6 3;4 3 2 1];
sum((x-y).^2,2)
```

Especially when processing many small sets of data, this can be a significant speed-up. For many functions (e.g. `sum`) you can see that the build in functions have a `dim` parameter which allows to select the dimension on which the operation should be executed. This is a more generic way which increases the reusability. In  this case, allowing to select the dimension is trivial

```
yourfun(x,y,dim)=sum((x-y).^2,dim)
```

Answer (score 0):

So what is the difference between `sum(x.^2)` and `x*x'` for `1xN` vectors in Matlab?

Surprisingly there is one. Execution is five times faster in the multiplication case.

```
x = rand(1, 1e6);

tic;
for i = 1:1e2
    x * x';
end;
toc;

tic;
for i = 1:1e2
    sum(x.^2);
end;
toc;
```

gives on 2012b:

```
Elapsed time is 0.057315 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.289310 seconds.
```